# R optimx different values with different implementations

Tags: r, optimization, hive

I am using optimx package in R to solve an optimization problem. I have a very large data set stored in hadoop and I am trying to use hive streaming with R to solve the problem.

**Method 1** :- Using hive streaming with R code.

**Method 2** :- Running the code from R console on the same server using

```
 R CMD BATCH
```

For example, below is a sample of the dataset that is used for both the cases.

```
  ITM_NBR FAM_ID OLD_PRICE MIN_COMP MAX_COMP ELAST Units PTC_FAM_ID PTC_ITM_NBR
1   64430 101006     59.98   50.983   68.977     1   230  AB_101006     AB64430
2   16961 101006     59.98   50.983   68.977     1   151  AB_101006     AB16961
```

Below is the R code I am using to read data from Hive table and CSV files to calculate optimal value. The  only difference between two methods is the way that I read the data.

```
##library required for the program
library(optimx)  

##Variables required for this program
lb = numeric(5)  
ub = numeric(5)  
exprvec <- expression()  
o <- el <- u <- numeric(2) 

#**Method 1**     
f <- file("stdin")  
open(f)  
e = read.table(f)  

#**Method 2**            
e <- read.csv('Dataset1.csv') 


names(e) <-   c("ITM_NBR","FAM_ID","OLD_PRICE","MIN_COMP","MAX_COMP","ELAST","Units","PTC_FAM_ID","PTC_ITM_NBR","MIN_E","MAX_E")  
lb <-  max(e$MIN_COMP,e$MIN_E)  
ub <- min(e$MAX_COMP,e$MAX_E)  
x0 <- mean(c(lb,ub),rm.na = TRUE)  
for(j in 1:nrow(e)){  
  o[j] = e$OLD_PRICE[j]  
  el[j] = e$ELAST[j]  
  u[j] = e$Units[j]  
  exprvec[[j]] <- substitute(x*(1-(x-o)*el/o)*u,list(o=o[j],el=el[j],u=u[j]))  
}  

eval_obj_f <- function(x){  
sum(sapply(exprvec, eval, envir=list(x=x)))  
}  


## Required options for the optimx package and algorithms

res <- optimx(par = y,fn=eval_obj_f,gr=NULL,lower= lb,upper= ub,method="L-   BFGS-B",control=list(maximize = TRUE))  
print(res) 

#**Method 1 Invocation**
hive> from(select ITM_NBR,FAM_ID,OLD_PRICE,MIN_COMP,MAX_COMP,ELAST,UNITS,PTC_FAM_ID,PTC_ITM_NBR,MIN_E,MAX_E from rtable distribute by PTC_FAM_ID)t1 insert overwrite directory '/user/rapp/t1' reduce ITM_NBR,FAM_ID,OLD_PRICE,MIN_COMP,MAX_COMP,ELAST,UNITS,PTC_FAM_ID,PTC_ITM_NBR,MIN_E,MAX_E using 'rscript.r'; 


#**Method 2 Invocation**  
[m1.hdp22] R CMD BATCH optim.r 



#**Method 1 results**  

    lb= 50.983  
    ub= 62.979  
    x0= 56.981  

                p1          value fevals gevals niter convcode kkt1 kkt2 xtimes  
    L-BFGS-B 59.98   2.285238e+04      4      4    NA        0 TRUE TRUE  0.001  

#**Method 2 results**  

    lb= 50.983  
    ub= 62.979  
    x0= 56.981  

                   p1   value fevals gevals niter convcode kkt1 kkt2 xtimes  
    L-BFGS-B 53.05923 23247.9      4      4    NA        0 TRUE TRUE  0.001
```

Comment: So, have you looked at `str(.)` on the two different data-objects?

Comment: I was having trouble adding the formatted code. I have just added the code that I am using.

Comment: It's not that difficult. Create an `e.1 <- read.table(f)` and an `e.2 <- read.csv('Dataset1.csv')` and show what `str(e.1)` and `str(e.2)` produce.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust. One of the column in hive table is defined as int instead of float. Once that is corrected the results are now matching.

Comment: So should this be marked SOLVED?

Comment: Yes it can be marked as solved